# Google Drive AppData Folder is not the same on different devices

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have a problem with syncing data on Google AppDataFolder. I install an identical app on two of my devices and check in the Log file. It show that DriveIDs of App Data Folder is not the same. And because the folder IDs are different, everything is different.Therefore my two devices could not communicate data with each others, even that i use the same Google Email account to login on both.

Is it correct with Google Drive AppData Folder? Or i have done sth wrong so that data could not be synced?
I wonder if I re-flash my device with a different firmware, will the AppData Folder ID  still be the same? If it's different, then Google Drive solution is completely a waste of time.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899129/android-access-google-drive-appdata-folder-from-another-device-but-same-app?rq=1) if it can help you with your problem :)

Comment: Thank you Kendi. I believe that the problem stem from delay in Synchronization of Play Services.